# @Schedule annotation with multiple Timezone

Tags: spring, schedule

HiTeam,

I have a requirement where i have to run a schedule task with multiple timezone at the same time that is 9 PM.I have used @Schedule annotation and add repeatable @Schedule  annotation.By this single File is running in two time zone at 9 PM. Below is the code.

`@Component
public class TestSchedular {
private static final Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSchedular.class);

```
@Scheduled(cron= "0 0 21 * * ?",zone = "GMT+4")
@Scheduled(cron= "0 0 21 * * ?",zone = "GMT+3")
public void scheduleFixedRateTask() throws Exception {
    
    logger.info("Schedular started..." );
}
```

}`

But inside the function i need to know for which timezone it is executing currently.On the basic of that i have to do rest of my processing.But i didn't find anything for this.
Is there any way to find this.Please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to access the zone properly.

You could instead move your logic into a private method accepting a time zone and have two methods annotated with the `@Scheduled` annotation, passing in the corresponding time zone to that method:

```java
private static final String GMT_PLUS_3 = "GMT+3";
private static final String GMT_PLUS_4 = "GMT+4";

@Scheduled(..., zone = GMT_PLUS_3)
public void scheduleGmt3() { 
    task(GMT_PLUS_3); 
}

@Scheduled(..., zone = GMT_PLUS_4)
public void scheduleGmt4() { 
    task(GMT_PLUS_4); 
}

private void task(String timeZone) {
    logger.info("Task started for time zone '{}'", timeZone);
}
```

Comment: Ya this way i can do as of now .But i have to do it for multiple time zone so i am looking for a solution where i can fetch time zone from db and run schedule task for each at schedule time.If you suggest any this kind of solution then it would be better. But ofcourse what you have suggested will solve my problem as of now and thanks for this.

Comment: In that case you probably want to take a look at [TaskScheduler#schedule](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger-) in combination with a [CronTrigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html).